# cannot import Python-Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, python-module

I recently started out with python and i'm right now looking to do an app that shows my Twitter feed. So I downloaded a module(not sure if its called that) called Python-Twitter and installed it. But now everytime I try to import it I just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-0.4.0-py2.7.egg\requests_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-0.4.0-py2.7.egg\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests.utils import to_native_string
ImportError: cannot import name to_native_string
```

Does anyone know what I might have done wrong with the install or something? Thx

Answer (score 6):

In my case installing requests-oauthlib fixed it

```
sudo pip install requests-oauthlib
```

Comment: This actually fixes the issue - might be because of older version of requests library.

Comment: This is indeed because of older version of `requests` lib, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of `requests` version.

`requests.utils.to_native_string` is available since `requests 2.0.0`

So just update `requests`:

```
pip install -U requests
```

See more details [here on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954974/import-error-for-oauth)

Comment: After much flailing, this is what solved my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with your install. The method `to_native_string` should be defined in the `requests\utils.py` in your Python install.

I'm on Ubuntu, and installed the Twitter module, and can import it without any errors. When I look in my install, in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py`, there is a `to_native_string` method defined there.

The implication from the error you're getting is that in your installation, there is either no utils.py, or, if there is, it does not contain that method.

I would recommend checking your install to see if that is the case. If it is indeed missing, I would recommend axing your install and reinstalling. You might want to try a `virtualenv` environment instead, so it can act as a sandbox (in that case you can leave your current install as is, as long as it is intact enough to run `virtualenv` and `pip`).

If `utils.py` is actually there and does contain a method with that name, I would recommend running a debugger such as `pudb` or `pdb` (`pudb` isn't built in, but it's more full featured), and step through the `import` to see if that sheds any additional light.