# Same Interpreter(?), Different Package Version in Spyder

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, python-idle, spyder

I got this [import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954974/import-error-for-oauth), which as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24955127/2327821) indicates occurs because the `requests` package is out of date. I updated the package using `pip`, but still got the same error. So I tried `from requests.utils import to_native_string`, which to my surprise works just fine in either the command prompt shell or IDLE, but throws an error in Spyder. I checked the version of the `requests` package:

```
import requests
print(requests.__version__)
```

The version number in Spyder (`'1.2.3'`) is indeed different from the version number in IDLE or the cmd shell (`'2.7.0'`). I am a loss to explain why this would be the case, however, because  Spyder points to the same interpreter at `C:\Python27\python.exe` and if I check the version of python being used:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I get the same result everywhere: `'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'`.

Comment: Try printing `sys.path` for each. I suspect Spyder has separate libraries which are being used instead of the ones you've installed.

Comment: @Ken this is indeed the problem! Spyder points to the Anaconda library first, even though I changed it back to the default interpreter. How do I permanently edit sys.path for Spyder?

Comment: I don't use Spyder, so I'm not sure how to modify its path. However, you may be able to upgrade `requests` with `conda update requests`.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @Michael, are you using Anaconda's Spyder but installed requests in another interpreter?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I had installed Anaconda Spyder at some point, but generally use the standard interpreter. When I tried changing interpreters in Spyder, it let me do that, but still loaded packages out of the Spyder if it could (first on Spyder's sys.path). The easiest solution was just to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall Spyder by itself.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Spyder is amazing. Thank you so much for developing it! If I had one complaint, it's that IMHO it's way too hard to install. You should really include PySide in the Spyder installer. As it currently stands anyone who installs the program directly on Windows just gets an error message about lacking dependencies (PySide). I've used Spyder on linux forever and love it, but had not made the switch on Windows because when you first install the program it does not work! The first user experience of Spyder on Windows is googling an error message.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your kind words. I'm glad you fixed your problem. I've been thinking on creating a better installer for Spyder on Windows for a long time, but haven't had the time to do it. I'll probably go for it in our next release, so that Windows people can enjoy Spyder at the same level as Mac people (with our installer for that OS :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would check out two different possible issues:

1) Make sure that the .pyc file of the module that is importing requests is deleted - I believe there is a setting in Spyder to ensure the interpreter gets reloaded each time called the UMD?

2) Even though the interpreter is specified, make sure that the site-packages that Spyder is using is also specified.

It is possible that when Spyder was installed, it created a virtual env that copied the contents of the system site-packages at the time of installation.  While you may be updating the system packages, perhaps the virtual env that Spyder is looking at is not being updated?